# New activity page broken?

Tags: bug, status-declined

Yesterday the page looked OK but today this is what  I get:

[image]

As you can see the Impact pane no longer fits along the 1st two panes and in the Reputation pane things are in a mess, too..

I should say I did upgrade my monitor from 1920x1200 to 2560x1440 and set the system to 125% this morning..

Anything I could do to change that or to help the team to fix it?

The OS is Win8.1 64bit, Browser is FireFox ESR 24.8.1. None of these data have changed since yesterday, though. 
AdBlocker and NoScript are installed but their settings have not been changed either.

Just tested Opera and it works fine there..

**Update** The page looks fine again here as of today (2015-04-20). Big thanks to the developers! (The status-declined tag nonewithstanding ;-)

Comment: What browser? What OS? Do you have any extensions/add-ons installed? What happens if you disable them?

Comment: I can't reproduce using Chrome 41 on Windows 7. Or IE, Opera (current and vNext) and FireFox.

Comment: ESR 24.8.1? Isn't the current ESR 31.6? As far as I know 24.8.1 is not supported by FF/Mozilla anymore.

Comment: It is a bit dated but not having to keep up with the crazy update cycles is why I went ESR in the first place. Last time I checked Google earth behaved strangly on the (then) current version and the wife complained.. But again: Everything was fine with the exact same FF settings yesterday..

Comment: I appreciate that nothing changed on your end, but we have been deploying fixes to different problems people have been experiencing on the new pages. Things have certainly changed on our end (mostly CSS). It could very well be that the changes we have made are what is breaking the layout for you. Unfortunately, we cannot [support such an old version of FireFox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported).

Comment: Well, I would absolutely hate to make you worry about any more browser incompatibilties than you have to anyway ;-)  OTOH the activity page is not a sufficient reason to change my browser version; I didn't really like it that much anyway.. I will update my question whenever my status changes in one way or the other. (As for 'so old' It is just under 7 months 'old' but of course with HTML5&CSS3 this is older than it seems)

Comment: @Oded actually you do: "Supported: 37, 36, and **31.x ESR**"

Comment: @Braiam: I'm not on  31.x ESR but on ESR 24.8.1 which is the last version before eg CSS3 variables and other modern stuff..

Comment: Confirmed (both original problem and current fix as of 20-04-2015), even FF12 looks decent again! **Very Big thanks** for the fix!!!